# General solution of partial differential equation 2. order

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I´m struggling with a very easy second order PDE:

$\partial_x\partial_y u(x,y)=0$

I would like to know what´s the general solution of this equation. I found

$u_1(x,y)=c_1y+c_2 $  and $ u_2(x,y)=c_1x+c_2$

But that´s somehow confusing because this is no general form..

So which one is the general solution?

Comment: Notice that u=0 or any constant function satisfies trivially your equation, since it is homogeneous. The general solution of that equation would be a linear combination of the two solutions you wrote. To prove this fact let u(x,y)=a_1 u_1 (x,y) + a_2 u_2 (x,y) and substitute it in your equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function of the form $u(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$, with regular enough $f$ and $g$ so that the differentiation makes sense, solves the equation (and these are the only solutions)

Comment: $\partial_y(e^x+e^y)=e^y$, and $\partial_x\partial_y(e^x+e^y)=\partial_x(e^y)=0$

Comment: $\partial_x(\partial_y(xy))=\partial_x(x)=1\neq0$

Comment: You are right. My false remark is deleted. Thanks you.

Comment: Thanks, this general function satisfies the PDE. I read that the solution space is no finite vector space. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

$$u_{yx}=0\iff u_x=f(x)\iff u=G(x)+h(y)$$

Where $G'(x)=f(x)$. Thus, take any $G, h$ differentiable and they satisfy the equation.